# margin spacing problem

Tags: css

Hallo,

I using the following code from css play. this display a menu.

```
.preload16 {background: url(m_admin/m_admin_2.gif);}
.preload16a {background: url(m_admin/m_admin_2a.gif);}
.m_admin {padding:0 0em 0 1em; margin:0; list-style:none; height:43px; position:relative;
       background:transparent url(../images/menu2/m_admin_back.gif) repeat-x left top ; font-size:11px;width:650px}
.m_admin li {float:left; height:43px;}
.m_admin li a {display:block; float:left; height:40px; line-height:35px; color:#888; text-decoration:none;
            font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; padding:0 0 0 10px;
            cursor:pointer; background:url(../images/menu2/m_admin_0a.gif) no-repeat;margin-top:0em;}
.m_admin li a b {float:left; display:block; padding:0 60px 0 0; background:url(../images/menu2/m_admin_0.gif)
                     no-repeat right top;margin-top:0em;}
.m_admin li.current a {color:#000; background:url(../images/menu2/m_admin_2a.gif) no-repeat;}
.m_admin li.current a b {color:#000; background:url(../images/menu2/m_admin_2.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.m_admin li a:hover {color:#000; background: url(../images/menu2/m_admin_2a.gif) no-repeat;}
.m_admin li a:hover b {color:#000; background:url(../images/menu2/m_admin_2.gif) no-repeat right top;}
.m_admin li.current a:hover {color:#000; cursor:default;}
```

I want that menu in a table row...
so used the following code..

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td>123</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul class="m_admin">
                <li class="current"><a href="#nogo"><b>Double ones</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo"><b>Edit page</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo"><b>Search</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>123</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now in the middle row, besides the menu that is getting displyed..there is a some space left..there is some bottom margin..i need the menu should exactly FIT in the row..i have no idea, how to adjust that with margin..please help me...

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking, please rephrase it clearly. The middle column is exactly the height you specified it - 43px

Comment: http://www.shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/

Comment: @Eran :- If i used it in a table, in the middle row there is some space below the menus. Eventhough i reduce the height of that row from 43 to 38,some space is left..i dont want any space..menu should exactly FIT in my 2 row..thanku for ur help.

Comment: @MatTheCat - Thanku for ur reply.Once the menus are displayed. In each tab, i want some data to be displayed. So i am using tables. so menus come as 1 row. In other row table headers..and in other table data..i am new to html. if u can suggest me a better alternative, i would be glad..

Comment: Better alternative is to learn css-positionning, tables should be only reserved for displaying lists of data.

Comment: @MatTheCat - I am using that table, only for data. That is what i have mentioned in preious comment as well. Here in the post to make it simple, i have written 123. my 2 row display list of data.

Comment: I think we don't have the same definition of "data". Whatever apply vertical-align:middle; on <td> tags.

Comment: Eventhough i set vertical align as middle. There is some space left. I want the menu should <B>exactly fit</B> in the table row. No space should be left, no spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at something like this - http://www.jsfiddle.net/DPjnL/

If so, I have just removed all the height and line-height attributes from your css. You can find the html/css code attached right there in the link

Comment: Thanku very much. That helped me a lot. That is what i am looking for. To adjust the height of menus, i have kept line-height and removed all the other heights.